# Domain of the derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

When we work with derivatives is the domain of the derivative the tanget space or the actual domain of the function?

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is no difference but on a general manifold there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of the derivative at each point is the tangent space at that point.